# Filtering a specific value in a row

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if its hard for me to show it in writing, but I can definitely show it.

So lets say I have this table:

```
(`name` varchar(5), `value_name` varchar(18))
;

INSERT INTO Alarms
(`name`, `value_name`)

VALUES
('cws-1', 'linkupdown'),
('cws-1', 'linkupdown'),
('cws-1', 'performancedegrade'),
('cws-1', 'performancedegrade'),
('cws-2', 'ICMP-Ping'),
('cws-2', 'linkupdown'),
('cws-3', 'performancedegrade')
;
```

What the table looks like:

```
name      value_name
-----     ----------
cws-1     linkupdown
cws-1     linkupdown
cws-1     performancedegrade
cws-1     performancedegrade
cws-2     ICMP-Ping
cws-2     linkupdown
cws-3     performancedegrade
```

I want a query that excludes any records that have a 'linkupdown' in the `value_name` column where `name` = 'cws-1'

So the result would be:

```
name      value_name
-----     ----------
cws-1     performancedegrade
cws-1     performancedegrade
cws-2     ICMP-Ping
cws-2     linkupdown
cws-3     performancedegrade
```

It seems really simple but I can't seem to come up with a query that satisfy this result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dis you want an insert or select query?

Comment: Select query, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: `select name, value_name from Alarms where 
name <> 'cws-1' or 
value_name <> 'linkupdown';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT name, value_name
FROM Alarms AS a
WHERE name = 'cws-1' 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Alarms
                      WHERE a.name = name AND value_name =  'linkupdown')
```

The above query return all `cws-1` named records that don't have any relation to records with `value_name='linkupdown'`.

Taking a closer look at the desired output as stated in the OP, this might be what you really want:

```
SELECT name, value_name
FROM Alarms AS a
WHERE NOT (name = 'cws-1' AND value_name = 'linkupdown')
```

This query will select *all records* from `Alarms` **excluding** any records that have `name = 'cws-1'` **and** `value_name='linkupdown'`.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39b65/2)

Comment: is it required to assign 'a' to the Alarms table?  Also, did you mean to write `SELECT 1`? Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: @bLunt Yes, because in the subquery you need a way to discern `Alarms` table from itself.

Comment: Actually, your first query  you wrote returns 0 results.

Comment: @bLunt Yes, I know, I misread your actual requirement. I explain what this query does right below it.

Comment: Yep, I understand that. I ran the first query out of curiosity to see if it would return all "cws-1 named records that don't have any relation to records with value_name='linkupdown'."